# Uiswitch in uitableviewcell reset when scroll up or down?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a problem with my `UISwitch` inside a `UITableViewCell`. When I change the value of one switch then scroll up or down all switches are messed up. I use an array to store state for each switch due to reusability they are still messed up every time.

Here is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];


    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    }

    UISwitch *switchController = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    CGRect switchFrame = switchController.frame;
   [switchController setOn:YES animated:NO];
    //set its x and y value, this you will have to determine how to space it on the left side
    switchFrame.origin.x = 50.0f;
    switchFrame.origin.y = 10.0f;
    switchController.frame = switchFrame;


    [switchController addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [cell addSubview:switchController ];

    UILabel *label ;

    label=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    NSString *value = [[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label.text = value;
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;


    //This for persist switch state when scroll up or down
    if ([[[self.SwitchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]isEqualToString:@"ON"])
    {
       switchController.on=YES;


    }
    else 
    {
       switchController.on=NO;


    }

       return cell;   
}
```

Here is SwitchChanged event :

```
-(void)switchChanged:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *index=[mainTableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    if (sender.on)
    {

        [[self.SwitchArray objectAtIndex:index.section] replaceObjectAtIndex:index.row withObject:@"ON"];
        NSString *word= [[self.mainArray objectAtIndex:index.section ] objectAtIndex:index.row];

    }
    else
    {
        //call the first array by section
        [[self.SwitchArray objectAtIndex:index.section] replaceObjectAtIndex:index.row withObject:@"OFF"];
         NSString *word= [[self.mainArray objectAtIndex:index.section ] objectAtIndex:index.row];

   }

    [padFactoids setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:SwitchArray] forKey:@"savedArray"];
    [padFactoids synchronize];

}
```

I will appreciate your help so much.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint and looking at `self.SwitchArray` to make sure it exists (not `nil`) and contains the data you expect. At a guess, I'd your arrays are `nil` so your getting back switches which are turned off all the time.

Comment: @DBD than you for your response . but what i mean is not all the switches are off . I mean that whenever i changed one of the switches on the table view then scroll up or down they get mess up the one was off turn to be on and vice verse .

Comment: As ChrisH mentioned, you are creating a new `UISwitch` every time you configure the cell, even if a switch already exists. That is something you'll have to fix, but I still think you'll need to check the data model because I'm not convinced your values are saving in them like you think they should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether this causes your problem, but it will certainly cause other related problems.

Each time when a cell was moved off screen and a next one appears, the one that just moved off screen will be reused. 
But you add a new switch object every time to the cell. You are far better off creating those only within the `cell==nil` block. Give it a tag and use the tag to fetch the object upon reusage as you do with the lable object.

Comment: Thank you this was helpful.But now a new problem a rise whish is that my table have many sections and each has many rows when section 0 row 0 changes switch then all row 0 in all sections changed ? Do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

In your header file declare an NSMutableArray, let's name it **switchStates**.

In your viewDidLoad, allocate memory and add object with the string "OFF" according to number of switches:

```
switchStates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i; i <= switchesArray.count; i++) {
    [switchStates addObject:@"OFF"];
}
```

In your method which runs when the switch is triggered:

```
NSString *theSwitchPosition = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", switchControl.on ? @"ON" : @"OFF"];
[switchStates replaceObjectAtIndex:aPath.row withObject:theSwitchPosition];
```

After that, in the method where you create your switches:

```
if ([[switchStates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"ON"]) {
    mySwitch.on = YES;
} else {
    mySwitch.on = NO;
}
```

This worked for me, good luck..

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new switch every time the tableView is asking for a cell. You only want to create the switch once for each cell:

```
UISwitch *switchController;

 if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    switchController = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    CGRect switchFrame = switchController.frame;
    [switchController setOn:YES animated:NO];
    //set its x and y value, this you will have to determine how to space it on the left side
    switchFrame.origin.x = 50.0f;
    switchFrame.origin.y = 10.0f;
    switchController.frame = switchFrame;

    [switchController addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:switchController ];

    switchController.tag = 123; //Arbitrary number...can be anything 
}
else {
    switchController = (UISwitch *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:123];
}

//Now set the switch state according to your data model array
```

It's also generally a better practice to add subviews to the cell's contentView rather than the cell itself.

Comment: Could you please give me detailes of how to do so ? This will help me a lot .Thank you

Comment: Good advise. There is one "=" too much when allocating a new switch. And there is no point in calling `[switchController setOn:YES animated:NO];` as the value is set later anyway.

Comment: @HermannKlecker yeah the `= =` is my typo. You're absolutely right on the `[switchController setOn:YES animated:NO];`

Comment: Glad to have helped...you can return the favour by marking your question as answered and upvoting our reponses!

Comment: @user2323070 seems like you don't track changes of switches in some array/dictionary, aren't you? ;)

Comment: A new problem a rise whish is that my table have many sections and each has many rows when section 0 row 0 changes switch then all row 0 in all sections changed ? Do you know why this happens?

Comment: No i did have array to track states and update it in SwitchChange Method @art-divin

Comment: for sections you should use NSDictionary-based data model. Like (in objc-literals): @{ @0 : @[@YES,@NO,@NO], @1 : @[@NO,@YES,@YES], ... } where the key is a section number and value is an array which contains data for each row by index